# getting java.lang.runtimeexception java.lang.runtimeexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting `java.lang.runtimeexception` and `java.lang.nullpointexception` .Please help me with this piece of code.

```
package co.sds.iitr.bullsandcows;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView P1Num;
EditText np1;
Button btok;
String n;
int Num;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    P1Num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNum1);
    np1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum);
    btok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btNext);


    btok.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    n = np1.getText().toString();
    Num = Integer.valueOf(n);


    Intent in = new Intent("co.sds.iitr.GUESSACTIVITY");
    in.putExtra("Num", Num);
    startActivity(in);

}
```

Log cat for this code
http://imgur.com/CgMrFdC&JmHj5fk&iervlj8

Comment: did you add your GuessActivity to your Android Manifest?

Comment: Post your entire logerrors.

Comment: post GuessActivity onCreate code

Comment: Attaching your logcat as text inside your question will make it easier for other users to help you.

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?  The stack trace will tell you this.

Comment: would you please put your xml file. and specify which line " you cropped the image of the logcat and the line number is not displayed, please highlight or rewrite the line.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check whether your package name is `co.sds.iitr.bullsandcows` or `co.sds.iitr`

If your package name is `co.sds.iitr.bullsandcows` then change the following line

```
Intent in = new Intent("co.sds.iitr.GUESSACTIVITY");
```

to

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,co.sds.iitr.bullsandcows.GUESSACTIVITY.class);
```

else,

change the following line

```
Intent in = new Intent("co.sds.iitr.GUESSACTIVITY");
```

to

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,co.sds.iitr.GUESSACTIVITY.class);
```

in your code.

And also check whether you have declared your `GUESSACTIVITY` in your `manifest`.

And finally don't hardcode your class name in intent.

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to register your `co.sds.iitr.GuessActivity` in your manifest file and also make sure while starting activity directly explicitly specifying the name make sure for the case sensitivity of the activity name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be inside `GuessActivity` code, which you need to post in your question. Anyway, you should consider starting a new intent like this.-

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, GuessActivity.class);
```

Hardcoding strings is always a source of errors.